# insertar datos en una base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos

```html
<?php
  header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
  include ('includes/conexion.php');
  $acentos=$enlace->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


  $query="INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, rol_id) VALUES ('{$_POST['nombre']}',  '{$_POST['rol_id']}')";


  if(mysqli_query($enlace,$query))
    {echo " <script type='text/javascript'> 
             alert ('Registrado correctamente. GRACIAS');  
            window.location.href='index.php';
            </script><br/>";
    }
  else{

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
        alert ('NO HA SIDO REGISTRADO');  
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script><br/>"; }

?>
```

Tengo un problema que supongo que será fácil pero no doy con la solución.
Mediante un formulario, guardo datos en una base de datos. El problema es que algunos de esos datos, lo introduce el usuario y otro lo selecciona de un select.
No soy capaz de que coja el dato seleccionado y los demás a la vez. Se hacer una cosa o la otra pero no ambas.
Las opciones para el rol las muestra sin problema y el nombre lo pasa a la bd, faltaría pasar el rol.
Adjunto código para ver si me pueden ayudar. 
Muchas gracias

```html
<form action="insertarusuario.php" method="post">
      Nombre:<br />
      <input type="text" name="nombre" required />*<br /><br />

      Rol:<br />

<?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM roles";
    
          if ($result = mysqli_query($enlace,$query)){
              echo '<select name="rol">';
              while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  echo '<option>'.$fila["rol"].' </option>';  

              }
            
              echo '</select>';
 ?>

          <input type="submit" value="LISTO"><br /><br />';
          
  <?php } ?>         
   
</form>
```

Comment: Buenos dias, puedes pasar el php que recoge los datos y hace le insert?

Comment: Insertado, creo que se ve. Gracias

Comment: Hola, ¿en qué momento pasas `{$_POST['rol_id']}`?

Comment: @gema los option del select carecen del atributo value, por lo que el select no envía ningún dato. El value representa el valor que será enviado por lo que este debe ser definido. Más información en: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/option

Answer (score 2):

No estas pasando ningún valor en el select ya que no defines el atributo value de los option. Debes corregir esto por ejemplo:

```
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<option value="'. $fila["rol"] .'">'.$fila["rol"].' </option>';  
}
```

Por otro lado el name del select lo defines como `name="rol"` pero en php lo recoges como `$_POST['rol_id']` estos deben coincidir bien los dos deben ser `rol_id` o los dos `rol`.

Como nota adicional indicar que tu código es vulnerable a inyección SQL

Comment: Solucionado. Muchísimas gracias. ¿Qué quieres decir con que es vulnerable? ¿Lo puedo solucionar? Gracias, de nuevo

Comment: que te pueden meter sentencias y funciones entre comillas para joderte la base de datos (Resumiendo) hay muchos tutoriales para evitarlo o usando $sentencia = mysqli_prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sentencia, "i", $id_usuario);
mysqli_stmt_execute($sentencia);

Answer (score 1):

- En primer lugar envias `name="rol"` y recoges `$_POST['rol_id']` así que o cambias uno u otro
- En segundo lugar echo ''.$fila["rol"].' '; no pasas ni el rol ni el rol id